# C Segmentation Fault: 11 fgets

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am new to programming and have encountered this error when trying to run my program. I am using terminal on my Mac to compile it, which seems to work okay, but when I try to run the program, it just displays "segmentation fault: 11". I don't know what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. any help would be much appreciated. Here is the source code for my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int l;
    char name[l];
    printf("Hello. What's your name?\n");
    //scanf("%s", &name);  - deprecated
    fgets(name,l,stdin);
    printf("Hi there, %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `l`? Tell me that.

Comment: I am trying to get input from the user. l is the variable i declared to represent the length of the string that the user types in

Comment: But did you take the input for `l` before you used it in `char name[l]`?

Comment: no. How would you suggest i fix this? like i said, I'm new to this haha

Comment: `name` is not resizable after you create it. Since `l` is uninitialized, it has a random value, which gives `name` a random length.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&l); if(l<=0) {/* error */} char name[l];` But make sure you have VLA support..`>=C99` What you did earlier is an example of UB(Undefined behavior) As an exercise check the return value of `scanf`/`fgets`.

Comment: That fixed the segmentation error. Now the problem is that my program only prompts the user for the value of l and not the actual string. i am trying to recreate a function i saw in harvard's cs50 course called get_string which just prompts a user for a string and stores the input in a variable.

Comment: @JordanOwens.: That's because the `\n` that is there as part of previous input is not conumed by `scanf` and it is inputted by `fgets` and that's it. You should modify your code discard any `\n` from stdin. or just neglect empty lines.(only `\n`)

Comment: I played around with the code a little bit and found a way to get it working like i wanted it to. I am still getting 1 warning when I compile it, but I am a lot closer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The int l is not initialised or assigned a value, right now it'll take garbage value as size of array, that's why it need to be assigned or initialised.

Thank-you for asking...

Comment: Yeah I realized that after the fact. I ended up removing that variable entirely and only defined char *name.